# Possible to call executable Thor-powered script without calling thor?

Tags: ruby, command-line, rubygems, thor

I have a thor-based Ruby script, but I want to deploy it as a gem in people's `bin` directories that people can hit without having to do `thor mytool`.

So instead they'd just use `mytool`

Is this possible?

I know it's possible with vanilla `optparse` but I'd rather use Thor if possible.

**Update:** This is the code I'm using based on the example on the Thor page, but I get the error below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env thor

class App < Thor
  map "-L" => :list

  desc "install APP_NAME", "install one of the available apps"
  method_options :force => :boolean, :alias => :string
  def install(name)
    user_alias = options[:alias]
    if options.force?
      # do something
    end 
    # other code
  end 

  desc "list [SEARCH]", "list all of the available apps, limited by SEARCH"
  def list(search="")
    # list everything
  end 
end
```

**Error:**

```
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thor-0.14.0/lib/thor/runner.rb:34:in `method_missing': undefined method `start' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thor-0.14.0/lib/thor/task.rb:22:in `send'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thor-0.14.0/lib/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thor-0.14.0/lib/thor/task.rb:108:in `run'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thor-0.14.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thor-0.14.0/lib/thor.rb:246:in `dispatch'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thor-0.14.0/lib/thor/base.rb:389:in `start'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thor-0.14.0/bin/thor:6
        from /usr/bin/thor:19:in `load'
        from /usr/bin/thor:19
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make the shebang line

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

and then at the end of your script add

```
App.start
```

Comment: This works great.  Summary: call the file whatever, make it executable, change the bang line to use Ruby as above, add App.start to the end. Win!

Comment: Where is this documented? I had to search for examples on the whole net to figure out the shebang-start trick.

Comment: It isn't really. The shebang is the standard way of making executable scripts. The "start" class method that gets mixed into your Thor subclass is documented at http://rdoc.info/gems/thor/0.14.6/Thor/Base/ClassMethods:start. I do agree, in general, that Thor's documentation is a bit spotty though.

Answer (score 1):

You may find this helpful: https://github.com/lastobelus/cleanthor

I wanted to have a thor-based executable for a gem, with namespaced subcommands, but organize the task files according to the normal ruby gem lib/mygem/**/*.rb structure.

Answer (score 0):

Make the script executable

```
chmod +x mytool
```

and make `#!/usr/bin/env thor` the first line in `mytool`.

Comment: I tried this suggestion, it was good but now I have the error that I added to the question.

Comment: This seems to be a separate issue, more specific to you code and thor. Perhaps you should open a new question more fitting for this new issue?